# Using Gevent inside locust task increases exponentially

Tags: python, concurrency, gevent, locust

I have a web server whose REST API I want to load test. I use locust==2.5.1, python==3.8.2.

Locust Config:

- Users:3
- Spawn Rate: 3

```
from locust import HttpUser, task, between, constant_throughput
import configparser
from gevent.pool import Group


file_path = "./sample/sample.wav"
num_of_parallel_requests = 3

class FileTranscribeUser(HttpUser):
    @task(1)
    def file_transcribe_request(self):
        group = Group()
        
        for i in range(0, num_of_parallel_requests):
            group.spawn(lambda:self.client.post("/parse", 
                        files = {'audio': open(file_path, 'rb')}))
```

**Expected results:**
Rquests per second to 2 always

**Actual Results:**
Requests shot up from 0 to 66 and increasingly crashing my server that is running locally (locoust is also running locally).

I referred to this [article](https://medium.com/@Sudarsan_M/performance-testing-using-locust-with-parallel-requests-1f51a2065be4) for implementation:

Blockquote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you're looking to do is get 2 requests per second, I don't think that article is what you want at all.

What you want to do is write your `task` so it only does your `self.client.post()` call appropriately. Then in your Locustfile, you need to set a `wait_time` (see the [docs here](http://docs.locust.io/en/stable/writing-a-locustfile.html#wait-time-attribute)) that will be used to limit the time between users starting and running your task. You probably want `wait_time = constant_pacing(1)`. Then when you run Locust, give it 2 users and a spawn rate of 2. That will immediately start 2 users and only 2 users which will do your `post` call, wait one second, then be replaced by 2 users who will make the call again, giving you a constant 2 requests per second.

Comment: thanks for your comments.  I made a small error in my question, for users=3 and spawn_rate at 3, I want the rps to be at least 3. However, my rps without event is around 0.4 given my request latency is 30s. For the request latency=30s, how can I achieve higher rps?

Comment: How you accomplish that depends on the reason your response times/latency is 30 seconds. If your service can handle it, you can add users until you reach the RPS you want. If adding more users increases your response time/latency then that's a problem with your service that needs to be fixed and Locust can't help you with that. See also https://github.com/locustio/locust/wiki/FAQ#increase-my-request-raterps

Comment: Does the number of locusts users mean the number of concurrent users or concurrent requests?

Comment: Users. You define what a user does in your code. A single user could make many requests.